# Cannot get max resolution for my Asus PB278Q monitor when I connect it to my dell xps 2710

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution

I just bought an ASUS PB278Q high resolution monitor (2560x1440), when I connect it to my xps 2710 the max resolution I get is 1920x1080 I have/tried the following:

1. I am using a 1.4 HDMI Cable
2. I have installed the latest driver for the Intel HD Graphics card
3. I updates the BIOS for my xps 2710
4. I tried setting custom resolution for the asus PB278Q to 2560x1440 @60Hz p color depth 32

I got an error max bandwidth exceeded.

None of the above have solved the problem, any suggestions helps will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to this forum post, creating a custom resolution **at a lower framerate** may work.

http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/peripherals/f/3529/t/19484603